# Does BNF terminate on a first match?

Tags: formal-grammars

I know that the grammar

```
<expr> = <expr> + <expr> | <num>
<num> = 0|1
```

is ambiguous because it cannot decide between (1+1)+1 or 1+(1+1).  However, that would also mean that

```
<expr> = <expr> + <num> | <expr> * <num> | <num>
<num> = 0 | 1
```

would also be ambiguous because it couldn't tell if 1+1*1+1 is (1+1)*(1+1) or ((1+1)*1)+1.  Or does it distinguish between these by terminating the interpretation as soon as it finds one match?

If it does terminate on a first match, then would 1+1*1+1 necessarily get interpreted as the first option since it is possible to interpret the "main operation" as being +?

Answer (score 2):

You can't match `1+2*3+4` with `expr * num` because `3+4` isn't a `num`. The only possible match is `expr + num`, with `1+2*3` as the `expr` and `4` as the `num`. To make `1+2*3` an `expr`, you need to match it with `expr * num`, and then you can match `1+2` with `expr + num`. Finally, you can match `1` with `num` to make the innermost `expr`.

So the only possible parse is `((((1)+2)*3)+4)` and the grammar is not ambiguous.

It is not the grammar we usually use for algebra because it produces an undesired parse, not because it is ambiguous.